# .htaccess redirect non-clean URL with two variables to clean URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect [www.bostonmabl.com/400hitter/boxscore/?SeID=332&GmID=93091](http://www.bostonmabl.com/400hitter/boxscore/?SeID=332&GmID=93091) to [www.bostonmabl.com/400hitter/boxscore/332/93091/](http://www.bostonmabl.com/400hitter/boxscore/332/93091/) in the event that a user enters an old non-clean URL. Below is my .htacess file which I tried placing in both the 'root' directory and the '400hitter' directory, yet neither is working. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SeID=([^&]+)&GmID=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/400hitter/boxscore/index\.php$ https://bostonmabl.com/400hitter/boxscore/%1/%2/? [R=301]
```

Comment: When configured in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a leading slash, that has been stripped off at this point already. `RewriteRule ^/...` can never match anything in that context.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess rules. Make sure your .htaccess rules file and index.php are residing in same folder.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect to new URL in browser.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(400hitter/boxscore)/\?SeID=([^&]*)&GmID=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^  /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

##Internal rewrite in backend.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^400hitter/boxscore/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ index.php?SeID=$1&GmID=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

***NOTE:*** This solution assumes that you want to rewrite(in backend) to index.php(by seeing your attempted code) and pass `SeID` and `GmID` parameters/query string into it.

Comment: @Dan, could you please do let me know if this solution has worked for you?